# Pulling out users who "liked" each other from a dataset

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following:

```
create schema bv;
create table bv.user (id serial primary key);
create table bv.user_like (
  id serial primary key,
  source_user_id bigint references bv.user(id), -- user who liked
  target_user_id bigint references bv.user(id), -- user who was liked
  is_like boolean -- true = like, false = dislike
);
```

```
insert into bv.user values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
insert into bv.user_like values
  (100, 1, 2, true),
  (101, 2, 1, false),
  (102, 3, 1, true),
  (103, 1, 4, false),
  (104, 4, 1, true),
  (105, 1, 5, true),
  (106, 5, 1, true);
```

I'm trying to pull out only the records that both exist for each user and that are both likes. Here's my query:

```
select
  ul.id as like_id,
  u.id as user_who_liked
from bv.user u
left join bv.user_like ul
  on ul.source_user_id = u.id
where ul.target_user_id = 1
and ul.is_like = true
```

This returns the following:

```
| like_id     | user_who_liked |
| ----------- | -------------- |
| 102         | 3              |
| 104         | 4              |
| 106         | 5              |
```

The first problem here is that no record exists that links users `1` and `3`, where user `1` is the `source_user_id`. The other problem is that user `1` didn't "like" user `4`. How can I account for this?

The expected result:

```
| like_id     | user_who_liked |
| ----------- | -------------- |
| 106         | 5              |
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ji0DDet9)

Comment: "*no record where user 1 is the source_user_id.*" - well your query is not looking for that. It filters only for `target_user_id = 1`

Comment: Btw why are you joining against the `user` table at all?

Comment: @Bergi I'd need to pull out some other stuff like the username

Comment: The name of user 1, or the name of the user who liked and was liked by user 1? It would help if you show your actual query

Comment: The username of the user who is the `source_user_id`. My query is in the OP, I've added it a bit later after posting

Comment: If I'm user `1`, I'd want to see all other users who I liked and who liked me back, including their username. You're right though, I can just add the join on the users table later. In this instance, no join on that table is necessary, from what I've gathered

Comment: I think I got it! `select ul2.id as like_id from bv.user_like ul1 left join bv.user_like ul2 on ul1.target_user_id = ul2.source_user_id where ul1.is_like = true and ul2.is_like = true and ul2.target_user_id = 1`

Comment: In addition to `ul1.target_user_id = ul2.source_user_id` you'll also want `ul1.source_user_id = ul2.target_user_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`inner join`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) the table onto itself: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XbbBHZ3U)

```
select * 
from bv.user_like a inner join bv.user_like b 
  on (    a.target_user_id=b.source_user_id
      and b.target_user_id=a.source_user_id
      and a.is_like and b.is_like)
```

| id | source_user_id | target_user_id | is_like | id | source_user_id | target_user_id | is_like |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | 5 | 1 | t | 105 | 1 | 5 | t |
| 105 | 1 | 5 | t | 106 | 5 | 1 | t |

Only users `1` and `5` like each other. `(1,4)` and `(1,2)` are like-dislike pairs, `(3,1)` is unidirectional.

[`Greatest()` and `least()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) can stabilise the order they appear in, to get [`distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) pairs:

```
select distinct least(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id) user_1, 
                greatest(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id) user_2
from bv.user_like a inner join bv.user_like b 
  on (    a.target_user_id=b.source_user_id
      and b.target_user_id=a.source_user_id
      and a.is_like and b.is_like)
```

| user_1 | user_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

Or, if you wanted to get the pair, along with the like id that ended up pairing them:

```
select distinct on(least(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id),
                   greatest(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id)) 
       least(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id) user_1, 
       greatest(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id) user_2,
       a.id as "the like that made it happen"
from bv.user_like a inner join bv.user_like b 
  on (    a.target_user_id=b.source_user_id
      and b.target_user_id=a.source_user_id
      and a.is_like and b.is_like)
order by 1,2,3 desc;
```

| user_1 | user_2 | the like that made it happen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 106 |

Adding the names:

```
with pairs as (
select distinct on(least(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id),
                   greatest(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id)) 
       least(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id) user_1, 
       greatest(a.source_user_id,a.target_user_id) user_2,
       a.id as "the like that made it happen"
from bv.user_like a inner join bv.user_like b 
  on (    a.target_user_id=b.source_user_id
      and b.target_user_id=a.source_user_id
      and a.is_like and b.is_like)
order by 1,2,3 desc)
select pairs.*,u1.name half,u2.name other_half
from pairs inner join bv.user u1 on pairs.user_1=u1.id
           inner join bv.user u2 on pairs.user_2=u2.id;
```

| user_1 | user_2 | the like that made it happen | half | other_half |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 106 | Ann | Bob |